# react-native not able to connect to bintray

Tags: android, react-native

Seems like react-native(React Native v0.23) not able to connect to bintray.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not download protobuf-java.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5
>   .0)
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/
>   protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protob
>   uf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar'.
>   akamai.bintray.com

Similar issue:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5884

Does anybody has found solution?

[Steps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/getting-started.html#content) are the I've followed. 
**Update**: Getting following error now:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not download imagepipeline.aar (com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:1.3.0)
>
> Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/ima
>   gepipeline/1.3.0/imagepipeline-1.3.0.aar'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/imagepipe
>   line/1.3.0/imagepipeline-1.3.0.aar'.
>   akamai.bintray.com

Comment: Make sure your network is working fine. Are you inside a corporate network? If yes, then are those URL accessible to you.

Comment: @mthakuri Yes I'm inside a corporate network where facebook.com is blocked. But those urls are accessible.

Comment: Hey I tried next day, its somehow working now.

Comment: Great, I have mostly seen this happening due to a network issue.

Comment: Why are you on RN 0.23?